# post method not allowed when sending html form to the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I tried submitting form to send the data to the database but the post method not allowed http error 405

here is my php and html code

ps I have created the database called rent_history in mysql and it works so that one shouldn't be a problem

```
<?php

    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $payment = $_POST['payment'];
    
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'rent_history');
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("Insert payment information(firstName, lastName, email, address1, address2, city, state, postcode, payment)
            values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssis", $firstName, $lastName, $email, $address1, $address2, $city, $state, $postcode, $payment);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Payment successful";
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();

?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/php/connect.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="h2">Check out Page</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="first-name" class="form-control" name="firstName" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="last-name" class="form-control" name="lastName">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label class="form-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label class="form-label" for="address1">Address Line 1</label>
                    <input type="text" id="address-1" class="form-control" name="address1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label class="form-label" for="address2">Address Line 2</label>
                    <input type="text" id="address-2" class="form-control" name="address2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label class="form-label" for="city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" name="city">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label class="form-label" for="state">State</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="state">
                        <option name="state" value="nsw">New South Wales</option>
                        <option name="state" value="vic">Victoria</option>
                        <option name="state" value="qld">Queensland</option>
                        <option name="state" value="wa">Western Australia</option>
                        <option name="state" value="sa">South Australia</option>
                        <option name="state" value="tas">Tasmania</option>
                        <option name="state" value="act">Australian Capital Territory</option>
                        <option name="state" value="nt">Northern Territory</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label class="form-label" for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" id="postcode" class="form-control" name="postcode">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label class="form-label" for="payment">Payment Type</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="payment-type">
                        <option name="paymentType" value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
                        <option name="paymentType" value="visa">Visa</option>
                        <option name="paymentType" value="paypal">PayPal</option>
                        <option name="paymentType" value="amex">Amex</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h3 class="total-title">Total:</h3>
                    <h3 class="total-payment">$0</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block continue-btn">Continue Selection</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block booking-btn">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to only accept post method but still couldn't get rid of the error

Comment: Your server is not accepting the `POST` method. Please contact server admin or hosting provider. Please refer this  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Comment: You usually get that status code when the web server thinks a resource you are trying to POST to, was "static". Do you _have_ PHP properly integrated into your web server setup here?